# Periodic OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, pythonanywhere

I am hosting a web app at pythonanywhere.com and experiencing a strange problem. Every half-hour or so I am getting the OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away'). However, if I resave my `wsgi.py` file, the error disappears. And then appears again some half-an-hour later...

During the loading of the main page, my app checks a BOOL field in a 1x1 table (basically whether sign-ups should be open or closed). The only other MySQL actions are inserts into another small table, but none of these appear to be associated with the problem.

Any ideas for how I can fix this? I can provide more information as is necessary. Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

Problem turned out to be a matter of knowing when certain portions of code run. I assumed that every time a page loaded a new connection was opened. This was not the case; however, I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It normally because your mysql network connect be disconnected, may by your network gateway/router, so you have two options. One is always build a mysql connect before every query (not using connect pool etc). Second is try and catch this error, then get connect and query db again.

Comment: Thanks PasteBT. But that's where I am confused: for every page load or POST request, I open a new MySQL connection—I am not doing any pooling?